# removing a particular row from infinite tableView in android titanium

Tags: android, titanium, row, infinite

I hav created an infinite tableView

```
var  table = infinitetableview.createTableView({});
```

Then i have created tableview row

```
var row[rowIndex] = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({});
```

Now my problem is I can't delete a particular row in infinite tableView. Could anyone help me how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you using a module?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call `table.sections[0].remove(row);`

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewSection-method-remove

Comment: This method is for normal tableview.here i am talking about infinitetableview

Comment: Is that some 3rd party module? That's not something we offer in the core SDK.